# Inserir um Elemento numa lista com DefaultListModel [JAVA]

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

tudo bem? estou criando uma aplicação que necessita mostrar alguns elementos registrados em uma lista, que mostrarei através do DefaultListModel. Infelizmente dentro da aplicação ele reconhece os elementos que foram inseridos mas não como deveria, já que ele não mostra o nome do elemento mas sim o caminho da entidade, queria saber como faço pro DeufaltListModel reconhecer meu objeto e os elementos dentro dele como tipo String, não como código aleatório.    Eu verifiquei se os parâmetros estavam sendo passados(mandei mostrar no console, os elementos que queria mostar) e eles mostravam em tipo String , mas dentro da lista mostra como na imagem a seguir.

como que mostra: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu  codigo foi escrito da seguinte forma:

```
public class CargosConsultar extends JPanel{
Cargo cargoAtual;
JLabel labelTitulo,labelCargo;
JTextField campoCargo;
JButton botaoPesquisar,botaoEditar,BotaoExcluir;
DefaultListModel<Cargo> listaCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<Cargo> listaCargos;

public CargosConsultar ()
{
 criarComponentes();
 criarEventos();
}

private void criarComponentes() {
    setLayout(null);


    labelTitulo = new JLabel("Consulta de Cargos", JLabel.CENTER);
    labelTitulo.setFont(new Font(labelTitulo.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 20));
    labelCargo = new JLabel("Nome do Cargo",JLabel.LEFT);
    campoCargo = new JTextField();
    botaoPesquisar = new JButton("Pesquisar Cargo");
    botaoEditar = new JButton("Editar");
    botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
    BotaoExcluir = new JButton("Excluir");
    BotaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
    listaCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listaCargos = new JList();
    listaCargos.setModel(listaCargosModelo);
    listaCargos.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


    labelTitulo.setBounds(20,20,660,40);
    labelCargo.setBounds(150,120,400,20);
    campoCargo.setBounds(150,140,400,40);
    botaoPesquisar.setBounds(560,140,130,40);
    listaCargos.setBounds(150,200,400,240);
    botaoEditar.setBounds(560,360,130,40);
    BotaoExcluir.setBounds(560,400,130,40);



    add(labelCargo);
    add(labelTitulo);
    add(campoCargo);
    add(botaoPesquisar);
    add(listaCargos);
    add(botaoEditar);
    add(BotaoExcluir);

    setVisible(true);


}

private void criarEventos() {
   botaoPesquisar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          sqlPesquisarCargos(campoCargo.getText());
       }
   });
   botaoEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       }
   });
   BotaoExcluir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       }
   });
   listaCargos.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
       @Override
       public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
           cargoAtual =  listaCargos.getSelectedValue();
           if(cargoAtual == null)
           {
               botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
               BotaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
           }
           else
           {
               botaoEditar.setEnabled(true);
               BotaoExcluir.setEnabled(true);
           }
       }
   });
}
private void sqlPesquisarCargos(String nome)
{

             //CONEXÃO 
 Connection conexao;
 //INSTRUÇÃO SQL
 Statement instrucaoSQL;
 //RESULTADOS
    ResultSet resultados;

    try {
        //conectando no banco de dados
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BancoDeDados.URL_CONEXAO,BancoDeDados.USUARIO,BancoDeDados.SENHA);
        //criando a instrução SQL
        instrucaoSQL = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
       resultados = instrucaoSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cargo WHERE nome like '%"+nome+"%'");

       listaCargosModelo.clear();
       while (resultados.next())
       {
           Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
           cargo.setId(resultados.getInt("id"));
           cargo.setNome(resultados.getString("nome"));


           listaCargosModelo.addElement(cargo);
           System.out.println("nome"+ cargo.getNome());
       }



        }
     catch (SQLException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao consultar os cargos");
       Logger.getLogger(CargosInserir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente sobrescrever (*override*) o método `toString()` da classe `Cargo` para fazer ele retornar o valor que você quer que apareça. Deve funcionar.

Esse código que está sendo retornado atualmente é o retorno padrão de `toString()`, que inclui o hashcode do objeto (após a `@`).

Comment: Eu ainda sou leigo estou aprendendo, como eu criaria esse metodo?

  
  @Override
    public String toString()                                           .
    {
        return getNome();                                                 .
    }

Comment: @PabloAP Edite a pergunta postando o código da classe `Cargo` que eu lhe mostro. Isso mesmo, no código da classe `Cargo`.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, só foi sobrescrever o metodo toString() para retornar só o nome, muito obrigado!!

Acrescentei dentro da minha Classe da entidade cargo o seguinte código:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return getNome();
}
```